How can I implement jwt in my next js app using next auth with google provider as the first step to connect to a flask api?
I'm creating a web application that needs to consume a flask API. Authentication is initially done using next auth, but I would like the web application to consume a service from a route from my flask api. But I want this route to be protected and can only be consumed by users logged in to the web app. I was thinking about implementing jwt pera since at the beginning the session is started using the Google account with next auth, I am lost as to which is the correct way to follow.
